# Как расширить файловую систему в RAID Windows Server + MegaRAID Storage Manager

Tags: windows, сервер, raid

Может вопрос и банальный. Не очень во всем этом разбираюсь, по этому хотелось бы спросить у профи. Ситуация такая: Стоит Windows Server + MegaRAID Storage Manager. В одном из RAID дисков (virtual drive 5), начало заканчиваться место. Я достал 2ТБ диск, вместо него поставил на 8TБ. Он подключился, переинтексировался, появился. Но место осталось как было (14,5ТБ). Прикрепил фото для более хорошего понимания. Вопрос такой. Как расширить файловую систему диска так, чтобы появился полный объем. Спасибо.[image: RAID Windows Server + MegaRAID]

Comment: А вот никак. В РАЙДе все диски должны иметь одинаковый объём. Если они разные, используется только объём пространства, равный размеру наименьшего из дисков, а всё остальное недоступно.

Comment: А если создать еще один виртуальный диск, и добавить туда 2 по 8ТБ, будет работать?

Comment: Ну Вы можете, конечно, создать ещё один virtual drive, сгенерить там сегмент тома и подключить его к существующему тому, расширив пространство. Но надо чётко понимать несколько моментов. Во-первых, надёжность такого составного тома ниже надёжности отдельного сегмента. Во-вторых, РАЙД-5 из трёх дисков - это 33% потерь пространства. В общем. я бы рекомендовал забэкапить том, потом полностью его пересоздать с увеличением объёма, и затем вернуть данные. Да, дольше, но куда как надёжнее. И ещё - вот не поленитесь почитать теорию по РАЙДам - только не по верхам, а углублённо. Очень способствует...